# A randon number into a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this as scope in `book.rb`

```
scope :anniversary, lambda { |number|
  where('created_at > ?', (number).year.ago)
}
```

and in my `home_controler.rb` I have this

```
  def query_of_the_day
    day_of_the_week   = Time.now.wday
    books = Book.includes(:screen).limit(13)
    books = case day_of_the_week
              when 0 then books.over_1000_readers
              when 1 then books.anniversary
              when 2 then books.voted
              when 3 then books.followed
              else books.last_updated
            end
    @query_of_the_day = books.decorate
  end
```

It is an incomplete script (the backend dev is missed).

**I want to replace the number with a random number between 1 and 3.**

**How/where to add rand(1..3)?**

Comment: I realize this isn't your question, but I thought I would note that the [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) states: "Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."

Answer (score 0):

Write your scope like this so it can accept a random number:

```rb
scope :anniversary, -> (number) { where('created_at > ?', (number).year.ago) }
```

And from do the following:

```rb
def query_of_the_day
    day_of_the_week   = Time.now.wday
    books = Book.includes(:screen).limit(13)
    books = case day_of_the_week
              when 0 then books.over_1000_readers
              when 1 then books.anniversary(rand(1..3))
              when 2 then books.voted
              when 3 then books.followed
              else books.last_updated
            end
    @query_of_the_day = books.decorate
  end
```

It'll generate a random number between 1 to 3 and send it as an argument in the scope.

Comment: I believe the scope, as written in the OP, is fine. The use of a 'stabby lambda' (as you do in your answer) is probably preferred and certainly more common. As noted, the [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) states that "Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes." All that having been said, your answer as to how to pass the argument to the scope is super!

Comment: @jvillian thanks for the guide. Didn't aware of the "Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes". Will try to do the thing this way from today :)